# Framer-motion: onAnimation callbacks not called on child elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I have an animation setup like

```
<motion.div exit={{ opacity: 0}} initial="init" animate="loaded">
  <motion.div
    variants={variants}
    onAnimationStart={onAnimationStart}
    onAnimationComplete={onAnimationComplete}
  >
      Child element
  </motion.div>
  ...
</motion.div>
```

However, the child elements' `onAnimation` callbacks don't run unless I duplicate `initial="init" animate="loaded"` in the child elements like

```
<motion.div exit={{ opacity: 0}} initial="init" animate="loaded">
  <motion.div
    variants={variants}
    onAnimationStart={onAnimationStart}
    onAnimationComplete={onAnimationComplete}
    initial="init"
    animate="loaded"
  >
      Child element
  </motion.div>
  ...
</motion.div>
```

Is this intended behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're not understanding correctly the `variants` inheritance and functionality:

here it's an example of `variants` inheritance:
https://codesandbox.io/s/uotor?module=%2Fsrc%2FExample.tsx

in your example, for the animation callbacks and animation to work as expected, the `variants` prop is necessary in both `motion.parent` and `motion.children`

```
const parentVariants = { 
  init: { ...props } // parent animation styles
  loaded: { ...props } // parent animation styles
}
const childrenVariants = { 
  init: { ...props } // children animation styles
  loaded: { ...props } // children animation styles
}

// the variants must share the same "keys" in this case: "init" and "loaded"

<motion.div 
   exit={{ opacity: 0}} 
   initial="init" 
   animate="loaded" 
   variants={parentVariants}>
  <motion.div
    onAnimationStart={onAnimationStart}
    onAnimationComplete={onAnimationComplete}
    variants={childrenVariants}
  >
     Child element
  </motion.div>
</motion.div>
```

This SHOULD trigger the animations and callbacks as expected.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work anymore... "onAnimationComplete" is called only if the "animate" is directly on a motion.element key. It's probably a bug, cause the Framer Motion docs still show it your way : https://www.framer.com/docs/component/###onanimationcomplete

Comment: @Lex 
Current/latest version of framer motion 7.x handles this correctly, everytime the children end their own animation, the `onAnimationComplete()` callback is called accordingly.

Comment: U're right ! Sorry i thought i've test in every way possible but i miss 1 point : It's not enough that the element end their own animation, if it have children **on the same variants chain**, all the animation of the children have to end as well. On my projet, the element end his own animation, but have a child with an infinite waving loop animation, so the `onAnimationComplete()` callback was never called. We juste have to break the variants chain to make it work : recall just the `animate` key will do the job... easy !